# How to create new package on specific folder?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, nuget, nuget-package

We are keeping our NuGet packages on a network folder. I want to update the package on feed with `New-Package` command. Is there a parameter like Output path or a better method for this?

**Update:**

I can specify the output file with `-TargetFile` parameter but then I have to state the full file name for the package. I still want to use default naming so version is included in filename, I just want to state the folder. Any idea how I can do that?

**Unfortunately New-Package command has been removed by NuGet 1.7.**

Comment: Have you tried looking [here](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/creating-packages/creating-and-publishing-a-package) or [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/gg618501).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the simplest solution is to build your package locally and copy them to the network folder by hand. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Yeah, probably. I was thinking about some kind of push command in the package manager console with some parameters I missed.

Comment: Well, you can use the pack command with -OutputDirectory option to specify where the package gets published. See http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/command-line-reference#Pack_Command

Comment: But these commands are not available in package manager console.

Comment: I was indeed referring to the commandline NuGet.exe utility. You can add a Post Build command that uses that utility to package your project.